# Genymotion not working

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion, ubuntu-16.04

Installed genymotion on ubuntu 16.04, installed virtualbox from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads for ubuntu 16.04, when opening genymotion i got this error as below screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hzBc.png)

below is genymotion log. Please help

```
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion "2.7.2"
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("genymotion")
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [getGenymotionLastVersion] New version ( "2.7.2" ) available here: "https://www.genymotion.com/download/"
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] Genymotion is up to date
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel"
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "ffba2223"
Jul 25 23:11:01 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage"
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 4
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPU number is > 8 - Fix max number to 8
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 7966
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Error] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 1
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Error] Output command: "0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp"
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Error] [createHostOnlyInterface] Failed to create interface
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Error] "Fail to load vboxmanage plugin from /home/gauravv7/Android/genymotion/genymotion/plugins/"
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Error] VM Engine failed to load
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted.
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LogCollector] VM engine not available
Jul 25 23:11:02 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LogCollector] Creating temporary folder: "/tmp/genymotion-logs-tmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

oops, seems like update software center has some problems. Installed virtualbox via cmd(deb) as per instructions given on the same link as posted in the question. it works.
(i didn't removed the previous deb installation[double-click=>update software center])

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 vboxdrv is not longer in /etc/init.d, therefore you must run this:

```
/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

Then it should start working again.